# How to print a calendar using nested loops

Tags: python, calendar, nested-loops

I have an assignment that requires me to print a calendar after prompting the user for number of days in a month and which day of the week the first day of the month falls on. I am able to print out all the days, but I have no idea on how to push the first day forward for it to fall on a Tues or Thurs:

```
days = int(input('Enter number of days: '))
day_of_week = input('The first day of the week: ')
print('S M T W TH F S')

if days == 31:
    for x in range(1, 32):
        print(x, end = ' ')
        if x%7==0:
            print('\n')
            
else:
    for x in range(1, 31):
        print(x, end = ' ')
        if x%7==0:
            print('\n')
```

The sample output should look like this:

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 1):

```
days = int(input('Enter number of days: '))
day_of_week = input('The first day of the week: ')
day_list = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "S"]

print("  ".join(day_list))          # print day of week

start_day = day_list.index(day_of_week.upper())  # get index of the day
print('   ' * start_day, end='')    # print the initial spacing

for x in range(1, days + 1):
        if x < 10:                  # print an extra space if number is one digit
            print(' ', end='')
        print(x, end=' ')           # print the number
        if (x + start_day) % 7==0:  # print a \n when day is saturday
            print()
print()
```

output :

```
Enter number of days: 27
The first day of the week: w
S  M  T  W  TH  F  S
          1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8  9 10 11
12 13 14 15 16 17 18
19 20 21 22 23 24 25
26 27
```